# HTML issue / Activate through Powershell

Tags: html, powershell, authentication

I feel like I am a burden for asking so many questions, but I also know that you wouldn't be here reading this if it means helping another programmer understand and solve problems :)

So, I am trying to make a simple button that allows the user to go to a website, log in, direct to the time management, and click the "Record Timestamp" button. Basically, a log on/off button with one click.

Problem is, this website will not allow me to auto fill the username and password fields AND let the program click the "Log in" Button. See code below:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form_Login                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form_Login.ClientSize         = '200,165'
$Form_Login.text               = "Login/Logout"
$Form_Login.TopMost            = $false
$Form_Login.StartPosition      = 'CenterScreen'

$label_Login                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$label_Login.text              = "Click to login/logout"
$label_Login.AutoSize          = $true
$label_Login.width             = 25
$label_Login.height            = 10
$label_Login.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(40,10)
$label_Login.Font              = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$label_Login.ForeColor         = "#000000"

$Button_Login                  = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button_Login.text             = "Login/Logout"
$Button_Login.width            = 180
$Button_Login.height           = 125
$Button_Login.location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,30)
$Button_Login.Font             = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Form_Login.controls.AddRange(@($label_Login,$Button_Login))

$Button_Login.Add_Click({

    $ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
    $ie.Visible= $true # Make it visible

    $username="username"

    $password="password"

    $ie.Navigate("https://workforcenow.adp.com/workforcenow/login")

    While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;}

    $usernamefield = $ie.document.getElementByID('user_id')
    $usernamefield.value = "$username"

    $passwordfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('password')
    $passwordfield.value = "$password"

    $Link = $ie.document.getElementByID('subBtn')
    $Link.click()

})

[void]$Form_Login.ShowDialog()
```

So, when I run the script, it fills in the fields, but the button is greyed out. What am I missing? Something in the HTML code?

Thank you guys! Have a great day!

Comment: What is happening is the website has some javascript that waits till you fire a keyup on username and password before login button becomes active, `ng-keyup="enableSubmit()"`

Answer (score 0):

You can manually fire the `OnKeyUp` event like this:

```
$usernamefield.FireEvent('onKeyUp')
$passwordfield.FireEvent('onKeyUp')
#Side note, the equal length variable names here are just...*chef's kiss*
```

You might need to open the page in Chrome Dev tools and look at the JavaScript for the site to be sure that's the event they're watching for.  They could be waiting for one or both of those to send a keyup, or instead be waiting for a mouse over on the Submit button.

Or perhaps the button needs to be enabled itself?

Either way this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Lets talk about the HTML

Inside we see a few things

```
<button disabled="" class="btn btn-primary ng-scope" id="subBtn" type="submit" data-ng-click="saveUserID()" translate="signin.signin">Sign In</button>
```

We could have submitted the form like

```
$Form = $passwordfield.Form
$Form.Submit()
```

But we see inside the button the `ng-click="saveUserID()"` which points to some javascript processing that happens to the post before the form is submitted which means we need to click that button. On the button we see `disabled=""` which is the attribute used to make the button unclickable. So all we have to do is remove that attribute.

```
$Link = $ie.document.getElementByID('subBtn')
$Link.removeAttribute("disabled");
$Link.click()
```

That will submit the form.

Comment: That seemed to work wonderful! However, after trying to log in, it seems to route back to the login page again. I see what site it needs to go to, but it doesnt follow through after the script logs in

Comment: Im not sure exactly what you mean? Are you using `$Form.Submit()` Example or  `$Link.click()` example

Comment: Link.click. Your comment said that the $Form example could not work because the removeAttribute needed to be disabled. At least, that is how I read it